# ggplotly with horizontal geom_crossbar() not matching original ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, ggplotly

When I use ggplot with geom_crossbar() going horizontally, everything looks how I want it. When I wrap the plot using ggplotly, the reference lines become meaningless and in the wrong orientation. Please see code and snapshots below:

Data Setup:

```
df <- data.frame(
    trt = factor(c(1, 1, 2, 2)),
    resp = c(1, 5, 3, 4),
    group = factor(c(1, 2, 1, 2)),
    upper = c(1.1, 5.3, 3.3, 4.2),
    lower = c(0.8, 4.6, 2.4, 3.6)
)

p <- ggplot(df, aes(resp, trt, colour = group)) + 
     geom_crossbar(aes(y=trt,xmin = lower, xmax = upper), width = 0.2)
```

[image: ggplot with horizontal crossbar]

```
ggplotly(p)
```

[image]

Is this a bug with ggplotly or is there a workaround I am not aware of? I would love to keep the crossbars going horizontal because it looks better with my actual data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround would be to use `coord_flip()` which requires to switch `x` and `y`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

p <- ggplot(df, aes(trt, resp, colour = group)) +
  geom_crossbar(aes(x = trt, ymin = lower, ymax = upper),
    width = 0.2
  ) +
  coord_flip()

ggplotly(p)
```

[image]

Comment: This is fantastic, thank you. As a follow-up, is there a way to decrease the width of the outer box to match the first picture?